# Using CSS and JavaScript, I can click a button to slide an element into view, but I cannot get it to slide back out on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I created a [div](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) applying an onclick function to an image, so it functions like a button. I then created an outer-container *div* and within the outer-container is an inner-container *div* containing multiple *div*s, with each one containing a social media icon. The inner-container also has an in-line style of *display:none*.

I then applied a CSS animation to the inner-container *div*. In my style sheet, and added a little JavaScript code to display and hide the image when the button is clicked. On the first click, the CSS animation runs nicely, sliding the social icons in from the left and into view. However, on the second click, the social icons are simply set back to *display:none* and they disappear without an animation.

I tried adding a second class to the inner-container and applying the same animation, only changing the margins to slide it in the opposite direction and out of view, but I cannot get it to work.

Sample code:

#### HTML

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="hidden-social-container">
    <div id="hidden-social"  style="display:none;">

        <span>A</span>

        <span>B</span>

        <span>C</span>

        <span>D</span>

        <span>E</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
#hidden-social-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#hidden-social {
    width: 145px;
    animation: 1s slide-right;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
    from {
        margin-left: -100%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}

.social-icon-2 {
    width: 25px;
}

.social-icon-p2 {
    width: 15px;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hidden-social");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcsquaredprod/duha7brq/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Remove `animation: 1s slide-right;` from `#hidden-social`

2.) Add keyframes for slide-left:

```css
@keyframes slide-left {
    from {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: -100%;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

3.) Replace your JavaScript code with my modified one:

```javascript
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hidden-social");

    x.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x.style.animationName == "slide-left") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    });

    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        x.style.animation = "1s slide-right";
    }
    else {
        x.style.animation = "1s slide-left";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. Please see updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/mcsquaredprod/duha7brq/29/

This cycles through correctly only one time. After the first. the event listener causes it to slide right and then disappear. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MC Squared - Oh sorry, I tested it just one time so I didn't realize that. It is caused by event listener because it is fired every time the animation is ended, the event listener set display to none that's why it disappear without animation. We need to tell the listener that it have to be fired only after slide-left animation is done. I edited my answer with the event listener. it worked for me when I tested it but animation sometimes lagged little bit. I don't know why

Comment: Ah, it is working perfectly for me now.  Thank you so Much Vladimir!  I